# Which atom numbers are possible with three bound states?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-spin, pauli-exclusion-principle

> According to the Pauli principle, which atomic numbers are possible given three bound states?

I know what the Pauli principle says, but I don't know how to go about finding the atomic numbers. I'm also not sure what bound states means in this context.

Comment: Is this question asking which _atomic_ numbers are possible given a three-_nucleon_ bound state?

Comment: @probably_someone Yes.

Comment: Ok, then. Hint: use the nuclear shell model. What should happen to those combinations of protons and/or neutrons which end up at a higher energy than others?